# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (Аномалия)

Tags: php, jquery

Происходит что то не понятное, когда захожу на сайт "http://site/view/index.php/" выдает ошибку "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" и весь js валится но форму можно отправлять, а когда захожу вот так "http://site/view/index.php" то весь js работает ошибки нет, но формы не отправляются, подскажите как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Обычно такая ошибка возникает, если вместо скрипта приходит html-разметка.

> но форму можно отправлять

Форма отправляется в соответствии с указанным атрибутом action - скрипты для этого не требуются.

> то весь js работает ошибки нет, но формы не отправляются

Судя по тому, что различие в `/` в пути текущей страницы, предположу, что форма отправляется по относительному пути.

Что можно сделать? Выбирай:

- Везде использовать абсолютные пути
- Везде использовать относительные пути, но правильно их порсчитать
- Использовать тег `base` для указания базового пути и просчитать относительные пути относительно него (этот способ стал популярен в связи с SPA и ршыещкн api)

Comment: забыл указать еще, когда в консоли просматриваю где ошибка то подчеркивает это "<!DOCTYPE html>"

Comment: по поводу форм не правильно сказал, когда нажимаем submit то страница перезагружается, а в моем случае когда js работает при нажатии на submit она себя так ведет как будь-то я прописал для этой кнопки preventDefault() но я то точно этого не делал

Comment: Спасибо, абсолютные пути помогли!)